# How to combine these two array into one array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

Given these two array:

```
$name=array("alice","ken","wendy");

$frequent=array(3,6,9);
```

I try to combine it like

```
$data = array($name=>$frequent);
```

but it fails. Anyone can help?

I want this:

```
$data = array(
      'alice' => 3,
      'ken' => 6,
      'wendy' => 9,
 );
```

Comment: And whats your expected output

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: I want to take out the data from database and store in different array so that i can plot a graph for it. But there is a problem occur when i take out the data.
I just take out part of the coding.

$namelist=array($name);
$no=array($count);

$data = array_combine($namelist, $no);
    print_r ($data);

the output i get is only 1 data as there should be 2 data inside the database.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_combine`

```
$combined_array = array_combine($name, $frequent);
```

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function as

**Syntax:**

```
array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )
```

So yours is like

```
$name=array("alice","ken","wendy"); 
$frequent=array(3,6,9);
$result = array_combine($name,$frequent);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [alice] => 3
    [ken] => 6
    [wendy] => 9
)
```

Answer (score 2):

write like this `$combined_array = array_combine($name, $frequent);`

Comment: Write descriptive answers as written by other users. And use correct formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php

$name=array("alice","ken","wendy");
$frequent=array(3,6,9);

// One easy way is
print_r(  array_combine($name, $frequent) );


// Another lengthy way
while ( ($key = array_shift($name)) && ($value = array_shift($frequent)) )
{
    $combined[$key] = $value;
}

print_r( $combined );

?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [alice] => 3
    [ken] => 6
    [wendy] => 9
)
Array
(
    [alice] => 3
    [ken] => 6
    [wendy] => 9
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it manually.

```
<?php
    $name=array("alice","ken","wendy");
    $frequent=array(3,6,9);
    $combined=array();
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
    {
        $combined[$name[$i]]=$frequent[$i];
    }
    var_dump($combined);
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php